# Renting a car in Iceland for summer travel on main roads: is a "Mini" class car enough?

Tags: car-rentals, iceland

I am planning a visit to Iceland in early May, when the [road conditions should be okay](http://www.road.is/travel-info/road-conditions-and-weather/southwest-iceland-road-conditions-map/) on the main roads. I am planning on just driving the Golden Circle and Southern Iceland to Vik and back as two separate day-trips from Reykjavik.

On car rental sites such as AutoEurope, the cheapest category of rental is the "mini" class (not to be confused with the Mini brand of cars). However, AutoEurope describes the "mini" class as "Small economical cars suitable for the city and short trips". Some cars in the "Mini" category include the Hyundai I10 or the Ford Ka.

I am wondering if the "Mini" category of car is sufficient for the two aforementioned day-trips. The worst case I want to avoid is running out of fuel halfway...

**Edit**: Well, at least for the Hyundai I10, according to [this webpage](https://www.parkers.co.uk/hyundai/i10/hatchback-2008/specs/), it has a fuel economy of 50ish miles per (*imperial, not US*)  gallon (thanks Jim) (18 km/litre; 6 litre/100 km), but doesn't say what the capacity of the fuel tank is...

Comment: Just watch, that's miles per Imperial gallon, not miles per US gallon, so convert your fuel capacity correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's absolutely okay. These are the sites which most short-stay tourists visit and the roads between them are very good. I drove almost the same route in April. On a "mini" car class you usually are not allowed to drive into highlands but there are no such areas on your route.

And there are enough gas stations along the road so you can tank at any point of your route.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Just as an additional question, about how much did you spend on gas? I know it might vary a lot depending on car model and diesel/gasoline cars, but I'd be interested in a rough ballpark figure for the route.

Comment: Slightly less than 9000 ISK, 650 km, 45 l, Skoda Fabia, gasoline.

Comment: gas is expensive and if you  taking  credit card with you, don't forget the pin. In iceland you always have to tip the pin.

Comment: Fuel may be expensive but unless you bring your food and camp, is going to be less than journey, car rental, accommodation, or food, so it won't be a large proportion of the total budget.

Answer (score 3):

I have been to iceland twice. It is totally ok to have Economy (e.g. i10) if you are doing  Golden Circle and Southern Iceland to Vik. I booked i10 but got i30 because the rental company didn't have i10 at that time.